# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController"

Tags: ios, xcode

I train in the creation of programs for the iPhone using MFMailComposeViewController. However, an error occurs when compiling:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_ $ _MFMailComposeViewController", Referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol (s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use-v to see invocation)
```

Please help, what is it? And how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't compile code when working with CALayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968071/cant-compile-code-when-working-with-calayer)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You must add the MessageUI.framework framework to you project.

Here's how you do it:

- Select the project in the project navigator sidebar.
- Click on the "Build Phases" tab.
- Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.
- Click the '+' button.
- Choose 'MessageUI.framework' from the list. (You can use the search box to find it).

Comment: Hey thanks! Strange, because it's been months since I use the mail composer in my app and today, after updating a pod (`MWPhotoBrowser` by the way, nothing related to messaging) it started to fail!

Answer (score 5):

You likely do not have the necessary imports:

```
MessageUI.framework
```

How you add them can be found here [importing framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1)

Comment: If I'd know about that link I could saved myself a lot of typing!

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to type it all out either