# when I tried to add twitter frame work in my iPhone project i gets this error: OBJC_CLASS$_SLRequest.How can I solve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Twitter Framework in IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117122/twitter-framework-in-ios-6)

I have integrated `twitter framework` in my iPhone project.But I am getting the error provided below.How can I Resolve it?

```
"undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:

     ___32-[ViewController TwitterAccount]_block_invoke_0 in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out ur build phases, some libraries/frameworks/implementation files might be missing..

Comment: This may be the error you are getting in the simulator. Did you tried it in the device?

Comment: [What's wrong with people today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117122/twitter-framework-in-ios-6) On iOS 6, there's no Twitter framework, but a Social framework.

Comment: [Use this Logic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10838636/1059705) try it with Social.framework

Comment: Baka was right - in iOS6 you have to add Social.framework to target. Works for me.

Comment: add Social.framework it should be work

Answer (score 2):

Check the Below steps:

1.`#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>`

2. Button Action

   - (IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender {

   if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
       {
           TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
           [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Test Application! :)"];

   ```
       if (self.imageString)
       {
           [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageString]];
       }

       if (self.urlString)
       {
           [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gmail.in"]];
       }

       [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
   }
   else
   {
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" 
                                                           message:@"You can't send a tweet right now,You Setup The Twitter Account in iPhone Settings." 
                                                          delegate:self 
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
   }
   ```

   }
3. Check the Twitter.framework Available or Not:

[image: Check the Screen]