# How to implement the UI like iPhone address bar?

Tags: iphone

Anyone knows how to do this, including title, address field and search field, I have tried using UIToolbar and combine UILabel and UISearchBar, but there is always a separate line on the left the UISearchBar.

Update: I use the following method fixed this problem.

[iPad/iPhone uiSearchbar transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943994/ipad-iphone-uisearchbar-transparent-background)