# How to set backgroundColor for UIsearchBar with UIColor?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode3.2

I want to custome uisearchbar style?    please help me! thanks!

Comment: Have a look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139115/uisearchbar-clear-background-color-or-set-background-image-iphone-sdk