# Change background image of searchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, uisearchbar, searchbar

It's easy to change background color of a searchbar.But, I have no idea how to change its background image.There is no direct method.
I need help...............
I appreciate any given idea...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISearchBar clear background color or set background image \[iphone sdk\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139115/uisearchbar-clear-background-color-or-set-background-image-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 11):

```
UISearchBar* bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIImageView* iview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
iview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
[bar insertSubview:iview atIndex:1];
[iview release];
[self.view addSubview:bar];
[bar release];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBackground"];
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use an image as the background of the search bar, you can use,

```
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bg.png"]];
```