# UISearchBar clear background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uisearchbar

I have the following code for my UISearchBar:

```
 UISearchBar * searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for a tag";
    searchBar.delegate = self;
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

I'd like to change the white background to a clear color. How do I do this? Basically I want the **textField background color to be clear**.

Comment: Please try [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139115/uisearchbar-clear-background-color-or-set-background-image-iphone-sdk

Hope it will helps you....
Thanks

Comment: I face this problem recently , I have a different solution than setting transparent background image  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158702/ios-uisearchbar-background-color-in-ios-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make transparent Image, and use that image with below code.

```
[search setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_search.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I found that destroyed the search bar text field not the background, it should have been:

`[searchBar setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_search.png"] ];`

Answer (score 4):

If you are supporting iOS 5 and above just do:

```
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Awesome -- much better than linking in a transparent image file.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code to clear background color :

```
//to clear searchbar backgraound
- (void) clearSearchBarBg
{
    for (UIView *subview in theSearchBar.subviews) 
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) 
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good try. The transparent png hack works though:

`[searchBar setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_search.png"] ];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
searchBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 7, please use

```
[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

for ios 6, use

```
[searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a clear background, the "Search" placeholder is grey and as is the spyglass icon thingy.

```
[self.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search          "; //the spaces push it to left align as there is no left align for the UISearchBar
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thatSearchIconThing"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone]; //my app is landscape
[self.search setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
```