# iOS: UISearchBar background issue

Tags: ios, iphone, background, uisearchbar

I'm trying to change the background color of my search bar. I want this top view to be one solid color. Here's the code I'm using:

```
 [titleBarView setBackgroundColor:[ColorUtil colorWithHexString:@"1ABC9C"]];
searchBar.barTintColor=[ColorUtil colorWithHexString:@"1ABC9C"];
searchBar.backgroundColor=[ColorUtil colorWithHexString:@"1ABC9C"];
```

And below is the result I'm getting. Notice that there's some gray along the top and bottom edges of the search bar. How do I get rid of this?

[image]

EDIT: After adding

```
 searchBar.searchBarStyle=UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
```

I now get this:

[image]

So my original issue is solved, but now the interior of the searchBar is the wrong color. What property governs that?

Comment: What about your view hierarchy? Have you tried `[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Comment: This works for me. Please create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about your view hierarchy? Have you tried `[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Answer (score 0):

try:
`searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;`

ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html

Comment: Please see my edit. This solved my original problem, but changes the color of the interior of the bar.

Comment: @JamesHarpe : _just to put it out there..._ solution to the non-white searchbar field background, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12598711/2857130