# UISearchBar barTintColor not hiding in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, ios7.1

In my app, I am using `UISearchBar` in a custom `UIView`.

Following is the code to display the `UISearchBar`.

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 135, 230, 32)];
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
[self addSubview:searchBar];
```

In *iOS 7.0.3*, bartint color not showing,

[image]

However in *iOS 7.1*, the bartint color is not hiding.

[image]

Comment: What does [`backGroundImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/backgroundImage) do?  Or does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12598711/1971013) help you?

Comment: Yes. [searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]]; Does the trick!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that this does the trick:

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```